# Rails, joining/including on an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have a controller with action update, that updates `@foo`. If there is an error I want to add information to the instance variable via join/include. Such as

```
if @foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
  format.js
else
  @foo = @foo.includes(:other_stuff).joins(:more_stuff)
  format.js
end
```

That doesn't work (the @foo = @foo....). Is there a way to get this to work? ie get the error codes and params to be entered into the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have standard generator code to find the instance @foo that you are working with (`@foo = Foo.find(params[:id])`).  In that case @foo is not an `ActiveRecord::Relation` like you expect.  You'd need to run another query to load the record with includes, i.e. `@foo = Foo.includes(:other_stuff).joins(:more_stuff).find(params[:id])`, but I don't think doing that will have much benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Like Wizard of Ogz said, `@foo` isn't an Arel object by the time you are wanting to chain calls to it. The variable itself stays as an Arel object until it's data is needed. Like when you attempt to call `.update_attributes` on it. You're going to need either a second query (like Wizard of Ogz mentions), or a second variable (which would run a second query eventually anyway) like:

```
@bar = @foo
if @foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
  format.js
else
  @foo = @bar.includes(:other_stuff).joins(:more_stuff)
  format.js
end
```